# Reading model from model view returned from controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a action method like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Pc()
{
    var v = await context.pcs.Select(w => new Code.pcs
    {
        id = w.id,
        name = w.name,
        province = w.province
    }).ToListAsync();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(v);
    return View(v);
}
```

And I am calling this through angular http like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("Pc")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

My question is how can I read model that returned by controller in angular?response.data is dumping whole view's html.

Comment: Return json - `return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want actionresult to be retured.view not json

Comment: But you have asked how to get the model (`return View()` will not return a model - it returns html)

Comment: @StephenMuecke not just return View(). There is a model in it like return View(v)

Comment: That has nothing to do with it - The view engine generates html based on your model and return that to the client (not the model).

Comment: @StephenMuecke my take from yor comment is angular http is for getting data from web api and not for view model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131212/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller's return type to **string** or **JsonResult**

```
public async string Pc()
{
    var v = await context.pcs.Select(w => new Code.pcs
    {
        id = w.id,
        name = w.name,
        province = w.province
    }).ToListAsync();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(v);
    return json;
}
```

and in your angular code make a modification to read json and then bind this data to DOM as per your requirement

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("Pc")
    .then(function (response) {
     $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: i must return view model

Comment: Ok but you can not directly return viewmodel to anguar http get method response you must have to convert it in json as response.

Comment: then ur comment should be the answer

Comment: @Alex as you mentioned in question **"read model that returned by controller in angular"** in angular so this is answer of your question i think doesn't it?